# Python: Replace an emoji with a word

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, emoji

Newbbie alert!!

I have this dataframe:

```
DATE                                   REVIEW
nov/2014  O passeio ao penedo da saudade é algo que não ...
mar/2018  Lugar de tributo dos estudantes de coimbra e c...
nov/2015  Lugar cheio de história de estudantes, contada...
abr/2017  Local mítico da cidade de Coimbra, onde se tem...
jun/2015  É um parque e miradouro da cidade de Coimbra, ...
ago/2016  Um dos locais mais emblemáticos da cidade, e q...

shape=(6,2)
```

I want to replace some words, emojis, etc.. in that review using a dictionary imported from a csv.

the csv struture:

```
emoji;word
:);happy
:(;sad
```

My code

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

excel_file_path ='c:\...whatever path...\TEST_FILE.xlsx'
df=pd.read_excel(excel_file_path)

dicionario_file_path ='c:\...whatever path...\EMOJIS.csv'

with open(dicionario_file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig') as file:
    worddict = csv.DictReader(file, delimiter = ';')


text=df['REVIEW']
def multiwordReplace(text, worddict):
        for key in worddict:
        text = text.replace(key, worddict[key])
    return text

print(text)
```

Checked imported Dictionary

```
{'emoji': ':)', 'word': 'happy'}
{'emoji': ':(', 'word': 'sad'}
```

I've tried everything, read a lot of approaches and I can't put it to work.
It doesn't replace the strings that I want to.

Could somebody help, please?

I hope my question was clear enough, that I respected all the forum rules and thank you for your patience.

Best regards
PR

Comment: Something here is not clear to me : what do you expect to do in the first for loop ? did you forget any indentation ?

Comment: Hi yAzou, it was just a print to see what is coming out. Corrected. Thank you

Comment: Print out `key` and its value after this line: `for key in worddict:`. It will show `emoji, :)`, `word, happy` etc. There is your problem: you are replacing `emoji` with `:)`.

Comment: usr2564301, So, you are saying that my dictionary is not well structured (for this effect), right? I thought since it is a dictionary, python will know how to handle it(knowing that 'emoji' and 'word' are features names). Can you tell me how should it be and how can I do it? Thank you.